# How to cluster and eliminate in SQL - Google BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have some data with only 3 attributes

- name
- illness
- yes/no

I've been stuck on this all day. 
I only wish to create two groups/clusters
VIRUS and FUNGUS

A lot of the users have been exposed to both

How do I create a group has ONLY been exposed to VIRUS
then find the count of this group?

every time I keep making a query I keep getting people who been exposed to fungus as well.

this is the code I'M using

```
SELECT name
FROM `dieases` 
WHERE illness IN (342, 2345, 9282) AND
      name NOT IN (SELECT name
                   FROM `dieseases`
                   WHERE campaign_id NOT IN (987, 457, 1283, 2212)
                  )
```

it won't finish the query and keeps crashing! I cant show you the data I'm afraid as its private medical data! I need help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't played with BiqQuery, but this is a standard SQL way of doing it...

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN had_virus + had_fungus = 2 THEN 'Both'
       WHEN             had_fungus = 1 THEN 'Fungus'
                                       ELSE 'Virus'  END   AS exposure_type,
  COUNT(*)                                                 AS exposure_count
FROM
(
    SELECT
      Name,
      MAX(CASE WHEN illness IN (342, 2345, 9282)      THEN 1 END)   AS had_virus,
      MAX(CASE WHEN illness IN (987, 457, 1283, 2212) THEN 1 END)   AS had_fungus
    FROM
      diseases
    WHERE
         illness IN (342, 2345, 9282)
      OR illness IN (987, 457, 1283, 2212)
    GROUP BY
      Name
)
  IndividualSummary
GROUP BY
  exposure_type
```

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax ... yes, you may use an alias defined in the select clause, in the `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen : And the `GROUP BY` clause too :)  Thanks.

Comment: Thank you guys, we were able to QA this and it checked out. We were able to help create medical interventions!!

Comment: @stacker you're welcome. Feel free to upvote and accept any relevant answers

Answer (score 1):

One simple way would be to just use conditional aggregation to check your two conditions:

```
SELECT name
FROM diseases
GROUP BY name
HAVING
    SUM(CASE WHEN illness IN (342, 2345, 9282) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND
    SUM(CASE WHEN illness IN (987, 457, 1283, 2212) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0;
```

The first sum asserts exposure to viruses, and the second sum asserts *no* exposure to fungi.

Another approach uses a self-join:

```
SELECT d1.name
FROM diseases d1
LEFT JOIN diseases d2
    ON d1.name = d2.name AND
       d1.illness IN (342, 2345, 9282) AND
       d2.illnes IN (987, 457, 1283, 2212)
GROUP BY d1.name
HAVING COUNT(d2.name) = 0;
```

This approach works by asserting that no matching virus record for a given name also matched to a record indicating exposure to fungi.